# HttpContext.Current.Session Auto Expiration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, caching

I Have looked around quite a bit and cannot find the exact answer I am looking for.

I want to know when the variables/values stored in `HttpContext.Current.Session` will be cleared? Or does it never clear by itself?

Is it when the browser is closed? When the cache is cleared? When the session ends?

Also, does `HttpContext.Current.Session` run in parallel to other sessions (other users won't be able to overwrite variables saved from my session's activity)?

I have noticed that `HttpRuntime.Cache` is not parallel, so you can store things that are useful to all users and relatively static in here, which is nice, but I need some method to store information that are only applicable to the currently logged in user, and should not be overwritten by or seen by other user's sessions.

Comment: When session ends and each new request generate a new session so there is no overwrite prob occr.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Session` is the session for the current user.

It has default expiration of 20 minutes and the values will be lost after that. The values will be also lost if the user clears his cookies because the session id is stored in ASP.NET_SessionID cookie.

Here you can find more information about the session [HttpContext.Session Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) and 
 [HttpContext.Cache Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Just to refine this answer a little, the default expiration is 20 minutes [of inactivity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx#Anchor_2).